# How to operate with multiple databases in one query using MySQL C++ connector

Tags: c++, mysql, connector

I have some queries already written and the problem is that some queries operate with two or more databases. This is how I do it when i'm using only one database..

```
sql::Driver* driver = get_driver_instance();
sql::Connection *con(driver->connect(url, user, pass));
con->setSchema(database);

std::string query = "some_query";
sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt = con->prepareStatement(query);
pstmt->executeQuery();
```

Comment: whats stopping you from connecting to 2 or more databases by making 2 sql::Connection objects?

Comment: Why would you ever need to do that?

Comment: cause i'm operating with 2 or more databases :) .. @rossb83 can't do that..

Comment: is it possible to setSchema for multiple databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working now. I just had to setSchema for one database and it worked for every other database. Don't really know why. If someone could explain would be great. Thanks for all the help anyways guys!